# Select only participants with multiple rows

Tags: r, tidyr

| ID | score | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000000 | 1 |
| 2 | 1000000 | 1 |
| 2 | 1000000 | 2 |
| 3 | 1000000 | 1 |
| 3 | 1000000 | 2 |
| 4 | 1000000 | 1 |
| 5 | 1000000 | 1 |
| 5 | 1000000 | 2 |

How do I subset this database to a new data base including only ID's with at least 2 follow-ups?
Follow-up is resembled as "Time", whereas people with only Time 1 had one follow-up and I want to exclude them from the database.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can either use a frequency based on approach to `filter` the 'ID's having more than one observation after grouping by 'ID'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% group_by(ID) %>%
        filter(n() > 1) %>%
        ungroup()
```

---

Or in `base R` - also use `subset` to subset the rows where it checks for 'ID's that have `Time` value greater than 1

```
subset(df1, ID %in% ID[Time > 1])
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L), 
score = c(1000000L, 1000000L, 1000000L, 1000000L, 1000000L, 1000000L, 1000000L, 1000000L), 
Time = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option using `dplyr`, where we first `count` the number of observations for each `ID`, then `filter` to keep only the `ID`s with at least 2 observations, then remove the count column.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  add_count(ID, name = "obs") %>% 
  filter(obs > 1) %>% 
  select(-obs)
```

**Output**

```
  ID   score Time
1  2 1000000    1
2  2 1000000    2
3  3 1000000    1
4  3 1000000    2
5  5 1000000    1
6  5 1000000    2
```

Or another option using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[,if(.N > 1) .SD, by=ID]
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L), score = c(1000000L, 
1000000L, 1000000L, 1000000L, 1000000L, 1000000L, 1000000L, 1000000L
), Time = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```